# Downloaded video not mirrored after mirroring video in AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I've been trying to get my videos mirrored for a while now but I cannot seem to fix it. I've tried the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34200762/how-to-flip-a-video-using-avfoundation) as well.

```
 if let connection = movieFileOutput.connection(with: .video) {
        if connection.isVideoMirroringSupported {
          connection.isVideoMirrored = self.videoDeviceInput?.device.position == .front
        }
    }

 if let connection = videoDataOutput.connection(with: .video) {
      if connection.isVideoMirroringSupported {
        connection.isVideoMirrored = self.videoDeviceInput?.device.position == .front
      }
    }
```

The video gets mirrored in the app but when downloading the video to my Photos app it's unmirrored again. How do I tackle this problem?

How my overall code looks:

0. `automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession` is set to `false`.
1. Configure the camera by getting device input and adding it to the `AVCaptureSession`
2. Setting up the movie output like setting bitrate and for iPads configuring orientation. Here I should also set the `.isVideoMirrored` property.
3. Setting the session preset.

Addition of audio session setup:

```
    guard let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(
      .builtInMicrophone,
      for: .audio,
      position: .unspecified
    ) else { return }

    guard let audioInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice),
      captureSession.canAddInput(audioInput) else { return }

    guard captureSession.inputs.contains(audioInput) == false else { return }

    captureSession.addInput(audioInput)
```

Comment: How is your `AVAudioSession` set up ?

Comment: @Mr.SwiftOak I added comments to the body of my ticket that hopefully will answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this workaround to solve this situation, check it out it possible that you can find it useful:

```
extension CameraViewController: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            print("Error recording movie: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            processMovie()
        }
    }

    func processMovie() {
        let asset = AVAsset(url: CameraViewController.movieURL)
        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        let assetVideoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).last!
        let compositionVideoTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video,
                                                                preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
        try? compositionVideoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: asset.duration),
                                                    of: assetVideoTrack,
                                                    at: CMTime.zero)
        if self.currentCameraPosition == .rear {
            compositionVideoTrack?.preferredTransform = assetVideoTrack.preferredTransform
        }
        if self.currentCameraPosition == .front {
            compositionVideoTrack?.preferredTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0).rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi/2))
        }

        if let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition,
                                               presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) {
            exporter.outputURL = CameraViewController.exportMovieURL
            exporter.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov
            exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
            exporter.exportAsynchronously() {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowVideo", sender: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will investigate this with our project. Marking this as the answer since I feel like this will provide me in the right direction.